# Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be an injective homomorphism between two rings $R$ and $S$. Prove or provide a counterexample:

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be an injective homomorphism between two rings $R$ and $S$. Prove or provide a counterexample:
>
> $R$ is a field implies that $S$ is a field.
>
> $R$ has an identity implies $S$ has an identity.
>
> $R$ is commutative implies $S$ is commutative.

I am using the map $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M(\mathbb{R})$ to consider because $\phi$ is an injective homomorphism, but I cannot seem to think of how to prove any of the properties.

Comment: What is the definition of homomorphism?

Comment: If $R$ and $S$ are rings, then a function $f: R \rightarrow S$ is a homomorphism if $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So there is a morphism from the trivial ring to any ring. For the first counterexample: can you construct a  ring from a field?

Comment: For non-trivial counterexample for the last two statements take $R$ to be the additive group generated by $1 \in S$.

Comment: But I'm not studying group theory. I need to prove using ring theory.

Answer (score 2):

> $R$ is a field implies that $S$ is a field.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ embedded inside the ring of $2 \times 2$ real matrices or the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.

> $R$ has an identity implies $S$ has an identity.

The trivial ring embeds inside any ring.

> $R$ is commutative implies $S$ is commutative.

Again, consider the trivial ring, or the example with real matrices above.